# What does the Information Icon means in Eclipse?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

There is an "i" icon in one of my xml file :
[image: Information Icon]

In the Eclipse doc, I found that it is an "Information" Icon
http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

But what kind of information it means? How is my "primeExceptionnelle" giving me information? When I move my mouse on it, nothing appears: no tooltip, neither the underlined name "primeExceptionnelle"

Comment: which version of eclipse and what editor is that?

Comment: This _i(nformation)_ marker is set by the Spring Tool Suite (STS). Its meaning is related to Spring.

Comment: @howlger Indeed I work on STS, but since it was on the Eclipse doc, I thought it was only used by it. So it only means that it is related to Spring ?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ As I said to howler, I work on STS (3.8.4) which is currently based on Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3).

Comment: The icon and the possibility to add markers comes from Eclipse, but it is set by STS. Therefore you have to search the Spring documentation for its meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, with all my research, it seems that this is just an indication that my code could be refactored.
From the Eclipse (and Spring Tool Suit) documentation http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm :

> Information -
>       A problem described as Information will not affect the refactoring in any way, nor will it negatively affect the code in the workbench. You can most likely ignore this type of problem.

And it effectively could be refactored using the "p" suffix instead of  :

```
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
```

and then using it like this :

[image: Refactoring]

My only remaining problem is that this Information Icon doesn't appear on the Problems View of Eclipse/STS.